# Getting minimum latitude of centroid geometries in a folder using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, geometry, centroids

My goal is to print names of feature classes and corresponding minimum latitude of centroids of geometry for all shapefiles in a folder. In total I have 5 shapefiles and I'm trying to loop through them.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\username\dataset_folder"

for z in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    print(z)
```

I am able to print the names of these shapefiles but don't know how to get minimum latitude of centroids of geometry.

What ArcPy tool should I use to get these minimum latitude of centroids of geometries?

Comment: Or just `SHAPE@Y` to make it simpler (a double, instead of a tuple).

Answer (score 4):

This might work (untested):

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\username\dataset_folder"

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    minLatitude = min(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@Y"))
    print("{}: {}".format(fc, minLatitude))
```

(Updated to include PaulH's suggested modification/simplification.)

Comment: That worked! I was trying to wrap my for loop under SearchCursor instead of the other way around! Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: would `min(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@Y"))` work? (I don't have access to arcpy at the moment?

Comment: min(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@Y")) worked too! 

A follow up question, I keep seeing similar syntax to "y for y in" what would be a good search term to understand this kind of for loops? I haven't really encountered them before until a week ago.

Comment: It's Python's "list comprehension" syntax.  See:  https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp .  It's a great shorthand for some `for` loops, and optionally `for` loops with `if` conditions and other variations.

Comment: @PaulH - thanks... I've updated the answer to use your suggested improvement.  Makes sense!